# C macro that concats two templated types

Tags: c++, macros

I my C++ project I would like to create a new type and automatically create a variable of the type. Suppose we have a 2 typename template struct `my_struct`

Now I am using

```
#define FOO(a,b) my_struct<a,b> var_ ## a ## b
```

which works fine when using POD types or simple structure names, like

```
FOO(int,double)
FOO(string,double)
```

But it doesn't work with C++ template types.

```
FOO(vector<int>,map<int,double>)
```

Is there any solution for it?

I wouldn't like to require a `typedef` workaround solution to use the macro

```
typedef my_vec = vector<int>
```

Comment: What do you need this for? What's the use of `FOO(int,double)` == `intdouble`?

Comment: `##` is for concatenation, `#` is for stringification. Your `FOO(vector<int>,map<int,double>)` yields `vector<int>map<int,double>`

Comment: Is there any way to drop `<>` using macros or other. I need to automatically create variable names in a more complicated implementation

Comment: @ztik If you need this to create variable names, maybe you could use variable templates instead?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I need to automatically give a name to the variable.
The basic example `template<class T> constexpr T pi = T(3.1415926535897932385L);` has a user defined name `pi`.

Comment: @ztik Can you explain why you need it? In what way generating a variable name is better than using a template variable?

Comment: It's still unclear. What stops you from using `template <typename A, typename B> my_struct<A, B> var;`?